# Incorrect value of infinite sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

Wolfram Alpha and *Mathematica* give an incorrect result (numerically) for the following infinite sum:

```
N[Sum[((-1)^n)/(n - (-1)^n), {n, 1, Infinity}]]
(* 0.700059 *)
```

Here's the [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_n=1%5EOO%20%28%28-1%29%5En%29/%28n%20-%20%28-1%29%5En%29) on Wolfram Alpha. Why the series isn't correctly evaluated?
The answer should be $\log(2)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [`NSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSum.html):

> You should realize that with sufficiently pathological summands, the algorithms used by NSum can give wrong answers. In most cases, you can test the answer by looking at its sensitivity to changes in the setting of options for NSum.

For instance:

```
NSum[((-1)^n)/(n - (-1)^n), {n, 1, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> 100000]

(* 0.693149 - 5.15666*10^-7 I *)
```

which is closer to `Log[2] = 0.693147…`.

---

**Aside**

One can do the sum in *Mathematica* if the partial sum is found by summing the odd and even parts separately:

```
Sum[((-1)^n)/(n - (-1)^n) /. n -> 2 k, {k, 1, n0}] +
  Sum[((-1)^n)/(n - (-1)^n) /. n -> 2 k - 1, {k, 1, n0}] // FullSimplify

(* 1/2 (HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) + n0] - HarmonicNumber[n0] + Log[4]) *)

Limit[1/2 (HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) + n0] - HarmonicNumber[n0] + Log[4]), n0 -> Infinity]

(* Log[2] *)
```

More succinctly and quicker (along the lines of [A.G.'s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7060/a-g) comment):

```
Sum[((-1)^n)/(n - (-1)^n), {k, 1, Infinity}, {n, 2 k - 1, 2 k}]

(* Log[2] *)
```

These two are mathematically equivalent, since the partial sums are sums of an even number of terms of the original series.  As alluded to in a comment, it is valid because the n-th term approaches zero, which implies the difference between consecutive partial sums of the original series approaches zero.  Contrast with Euler's counterexample, `Sum[(-1)^n, {n, 1, Infinity}]`.

Comment: @Chris'ssis Michael is citing the help ...

Comment: @Chris'ssis It's what the documentation says, anyway. :)  In other words, the results you get from `N@Sum` should be verified.  The summand is alternating and non-monotonic, which is kind of pathological, I suppose.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, OK! (+1) Anyway there is nothing pathological here ...

Comment: @Chris'ssis No problem.  I think what seems "pathological" to us and what is "pathological" to `NSum`'s algorithms might not be the same thing.

Comment: `Quiet@NLimit[
   NSum[((-1)^n)/(n - (-1)^n), {n, 1, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> m], 
   m -> Infinity] - Log@2`

Comment: @belisarius I wouldn't have thought of that, but it seems natural in hindsight.

Comment: Not so natural :) If you remove the `Quiet[]` you'll see `NSum[]` choking ...

Comment: Increase the `WorkingPrecision` in `NSum` will elimimate the imaginary part.

Comment: You can also pair up consecutive terms of the sum: `Limit[Sum[1/(2 k - 1) - 1/(2 k), {k, 1, n/2}], n -> Infinity]` returns `Log[2]`.

Comment: @A.G. Yes, I debated which of the ways to present.  I find it odd that *Mathematica* doesn't automatically try pairs when the sign is alternating.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think that is because MMA doesn't know if the series is unconditionally convergent (which is the necessary condition for term-rearrangement keeping the same convergence) or not, and I suppose it more expensive to judge that than just compute the original series.

Comment: @Silvia But pairing consecutive terms is valid, if the n-th term goes to zero.  (Isn't it?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm afraid I have to consult books, after so many years of being away from math, I can't remember such detail now... :(

Answer (score 5):

For `Nsum` several options for the method of summation is allowed, with `Method -> Automatic` by default. If to put explicitly `Method -> "AlternatingSigns"` it gives the result, though to get three true digits one has to take a very high `PrecisionGoal`:

```
NSum[((-1)^n)/(n - (-1)^n), {n, 1, Infinity}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 10^4, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]
```

> 0.6930394027669343

On the other hand setting Method -> "WynnEpsilon" gives a wrong answer almost as in the question:

```
NSum[((-1)^n)/(n - (-1)^n), {n, 1, Infinity}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 10^4, Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]
```

> 0.7015171756747272

Increasing `WorkingPrecision` and changing other parameters doesn't seem to help. So perhaps in this case not the best method is taken automatically.

Comment: You can also increase `NSumTerms` and `WorkingPrecision` with the `"AlternatingSigns"` method to help get closer to the true value.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried but strangely it didn't help. Perhaps this example is "pathological" in some sense for the methods used.

Comment: I guess you're right.  I tried "AlternatingSigns" at first and the result was worse with the default options (I think because the absolute values of the terms are non-decreasing).  You have to get `NSumTerms` pretty large before there's a sufficient improvement, 10^4 or 10^5.  Probably `PrecisionGoal` also affects how many terms are used.  It seems like it ought to.  So in effect, they're similar.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for answer (+1)