# How do I make an operation by selecting the odd number?

Tags: summation

[image]

n=odd number

I would like to select an operation and graph by selecting the odd numbers in the infinite area.
Please, help me.

Comment: Please post the code, not pictures of it

Comment: Related [(39316)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39317/44141)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you seek?

```
expr = With[{n = 2 n + 1}, 2/(I π n) E^(I π n t)];

F1 = Sum[expr, {n, -∞, ∞}]

Plot[F1, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

> ```
> (2 I (ArcTanh[E^(-I π t)] - ArcTanh[E^(I π t)]))/π
> ```

[image]

Comment: It was a lot of help.Thank you.